# How can I be sure that data is distributed evenly across the hadoop nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I copy data from local system to HDFS, сan I be sure that it is distributed evenly across the nodes?

PS HDFS guarantee that each block will be stored at 3 different nodes. But does this mean that all blocks of my files will be sorted on same 3 nodes? Or will HDFS select them by random for each new block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your replication is set to 3, it will be put on 3 separate nodes. The number of nodes it's placed on is controlled by your replication factor. If you want greater distribution then you can increase the replication number by editing the `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-site.xml` and changing the `dfs.replication` value.

I believe new blocks are placed almost randomly. There is some consideration for distribution across different racks (when hadoop is made aware of racks). There is an example (can't find link) that if you have replication at 3 and 2 racks, 2 blocks will be in one rack and the third block will be placed in the other rack. I would guess that there is no preference shown for what node gets the blocks in the rack.

I haven't seen anything indicating or stating a preference to store blocks of the same file on the same nodes.

If you are looking for ways to force balancing data across nodes (with replication at whatever value) a simple option is `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-balancer.sh` which will run a balancing process to move blocks around the cluster automatically.
This and a few other balancing options can be found in at the [Hadoop FAQs](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#line-173)

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the default BlockPlacementPolicyDefault strategy, placement of the first replica is only random if you're *not* performing the write from an actual participating data node. See the comment block near the top of that strategy's implementation here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/blockmanagement/BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java

Answer (score 3):

You can open HDFS Web UI on port 50070 of Your namenode. It will show you the information about data nodes. One thing you will see there - used space per node. 
If you do not have UI - you can look on the space used in the HDFS directories of the data nodes. 
If you have a data skew, you can run rebalancer which will solve it gradually.

Answer (score 2):

Now with [Hadoop-385](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385) patch, we can choose the block placement policy, so as to place all blocks of a file in the same node (and similarly for replicated nodes). Read this [blog](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/hdfs-block-replica-placement-in-your.html) about this topic - look at the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hadoop distributes data per block, so each block would be distributed separately.

Comment: HDFS guarantee that each block will be stored at 3 different nodes. But does this mean that all blocks of my files will be sorted on same 3 nodes? Or will HDFS  select them by random for each new block?

Comment: HDFS has rules how to select node for storing blocks. If you have replication factor as default 3: one copy will be stored on one machine, one on node in other rack, and one on different node on the same rack (if you don't have racks this should be 3 different nodes.